# Superfish CSS Navigation dropdown width

Tags: javascript, css, superfish

on my page: http://bn-servers.de i use the superfish.js and css.
Now my submenu have a big width but i dont know why.

my css code:

```
  /*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.sf-menu li {
    position: relative;
}
.sf-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}
.sf-menu > li {
    float: left;
}
.sf-menu li:hover > ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.sf-menu a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.sf-menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}


/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.sf-menu {
    float: left;
}
.sf-menu ul {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    min-width: 12em; /* allow long menu items to determine submenu width */
    *width: 12em; /* no auto sub width for IE7, see white-space comment     

below */
}
.sf-menu a {

    text-decoration: none;
    zoom: 1; /* IE7 */
}
.sf-menu a {
    color: #13a;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.sf-menu li {
        background: #302f2f; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #302f2f 0%, #000000 100%); /* 

FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #302f2f 0%,#000000 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #302f2f 0%,#000000 100%); 
    white-space: nowrap; /* no need for Supersubs plugin */
    *white-space: normal; /* ...unless you support IE7 (let it wrap) */
    -webkit-transition: background .2s;
    transition: background .2s;
    height:40px ;
}
.sf-menu ul li {
    background: #ff9500;
}
.sf-menu ul ul li {
    background: #ff9500;
}
.sf-menu li:hover,
.sf-menu li.sfHover {
    background: #ff7500;
    /* only transition out, not in */
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}

/*** arrows (for all except IE7) **/
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul {
    padding-right: 2.5em;
    *padding-right: 1em; /* no CSS arrows for IE7 (lack pseudo-elements) */
}
/* styling for both css and generated arrows */
/*.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 1em;
    margin-top: -3px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    /* order of following 3 rules important for fallbacks to work */
    /*border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #dFeEFF; 
    /*border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
*/
.sf-arrows > li > .sf-with-ul:focus:after,
.sf-arrows > li:hover > .sf-with-ul:after,
.sf-arrows > .sfHover > .sf-with-ul:after {
    border-top-color: white; /* IE8 fallback colour */
}
/* styling for right-facing arrows */
.sf-arrows ul .sf-with-ul:after {
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: -3px;
    border-color: transparent;
}
.sf-arrows ul li > .sf-with-ul:focus:after,
.sf-arrows ul li:hover > .sf-with-ul:after,
.sf-arrows ul .sfHover > .sf-with-ul:after {
}
```

Have anyone a solution for this bug?
I want that the submenu have the same width like the parent menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Remove width:700px from nav ul.

In your style.css line 943.

Answer (score 0):

The width of 700px of the ul refers to the css style information

```
nav ul {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 700px;
}
```

You could avoid this with the css child selektor ( > ),

```
nav > ul {
}
```

but pay attention on words like "Rechenzentrum", that would be to long.

Answer (score 0):

The min-width value is too much, you can change it to certain width like this one:

```
.sf-menu ul {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    width: 10em;
}
```